# indexing of Temptables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

Good Day to every one!

i have a migration process from a remote query, i fetch data and store it in a `#Temptable`,
the question is, what would be better? putting index after Creation of table of `#temptable` or insert data first in the `#temtable` before putting an index? and why? or it is better to process the data while in the remote query before inserting the data in a `#temptable`

ex.

```
        Select * into #BiosData 
        from sometable a
        where (a.Status between 3 and 5)
        CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_MAINID ON #BiosData([MAINID])
               **Process the data retrieved above....**
```

OR this?

```
        select A.MAINIDinto #BiosData
        from table a
        inner join Transactions.sometable c
        on a.ID= c.fld_ID
        inner join Reference.sometable b
        on cast(a.[ID]/1000000000000 as decimal (38,0)) = b.fld_ID
        where a.version > b.fld_version
            and (a.Status between 3 and 5)
```

thank you for your tips and suggestions :) im a newbie in Sql please be gentle to me :)

Comment: It depends on your data, I think it's better to test several approaches, but you have to get rid of join on calculated fields if you care about performance

Comment: @RomanPekar thanks for the tip! i think youre right about that! :)

Comment: temporary table could be useful - you're just put `cast(a.[PawnMainID]/1000000000000 as decimal (38,0))` into temp table and then create an index on it

Comment: @RomanPekar so you're saying that if i will use temptables it is better to insert first before indexing it?

Comment: I have not tested that, but from my knowledge of CS it's better to create index after insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a generic rule:
If you create a fresh table and are going to insert data into it and it needs an index then it is faster to insert the data first and create the index afterwards. Why: because creating an index means calculating it if data exists, but inserting data on an indexed table will continiously reshuffle the index contents which also need to be written. So by creating the index afterwards you avoid the overhead of updating the index while inserting

Exception 1: if you want to have the index combined with the data hence when a read occurs to the index t find a particular value it also has the data available in the same read operation. In oracle they call it an index organized table. I think in MS SQL it might be called an clustered index, but not 100% sure.

Exception 2: if your index is used to enforce some constraint then creating the index first is a good option to make sure that during the inserts the constraint is maintained.

In your case: I notice that in the complex query there is an additional where clause: it may result in fewer inserts hence faster processing, however if the tables used in the complex query have additional indexes which speed up the query, make sure similar indices are also created on the temp table.

Finally: indices are typically used to reduce disk i/o, temporary tables are if I am not mistaken maintained in memory. So adding indices are not guaranteed to increase speed...